# How IIOException has no no-arg constructor?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, arguments

Suppose we have a class NoArgConstructorClass in a file NoArgConstructorClass.java

```
/* first example */
import javax.imageio.IIOException;

public class NoArgConstructorClass
{    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        NoArgConstructorClass n = new NoArgConstructorClass();
        IIOException e = new IIOException();
    }
}
```

This code on compilation produces error: no suitable constructor found for IIOException.

Since IIOException should have a no-arg constructor (added by compilator), how it is made that there is no no-arg constructor for IIOException?

```
/** second example, showing that ClassB inherits a no-arg constructor from Object */
/** put in ConstructorChain.java */
public class ConstructorChain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ClassB b = new ClassB();
    }
}

/** put in ClassA.java */
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassA()
    {
        System.out.println("Class A");
    } 
}

/** put in ClassB.java */
public class ClassB
    extends ClassA
{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q. This code on compilation produces error: no suitable constructor found for IIOException.

If you look at the docs of [`IIOException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/IIOException.html), you can see that it does not have a default(no-arg) constructor. It has 2 constructors and both are parameterized(single parameter and double parameter). That is why you get the compilation error when you try to create a `IIOException` instance with the no-arg constructor.

---

> Q. Since IIOException should inherit a no-arg constructor from Object, how it is made that there is no no-arg constructor for IIOException?

It doesn't inherit a no-arg constructor. When a class is inherited, you either add a call to its super class constructor using `super()` or the compiler does that in case you don't do it. So the constructor of the `IIOException` would look something like this.

```
public IIOException(String message) {
    // if the below line is not present, the compiler adds it
    super(); // This calls the parent class (IOException) constructor and since there is a no-arg constructor there, its perfectly valid
    ... // other code
}
```

---

I re-read your question twice now, and I think you are taking the compiler's adding of a default no-arg constructor as an constructor inherited from the parent class.

As mentioned in the [JLS-8.8.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9)(thanks to the OP for the link),

If you have a class without a constructor(with or without arg), the compiler adds a default no-arg constructor by itself. **BUT** if you specify a constructor with arg and do not specify a no-arg constructor, then the compiler **DOES NOT** add a default no-arg constructor to the class. Let me cite an example.

```
class A {}
```

You can instantiate class `A` using `A a = new A()` because even if you haven't specified any constructor, a default no-arg constructor is added to the class.

But if your class looks like this,

```
class A {
    public A(int b) {
    }
}
```

In this case, you have a single argument constructor. You can now instantiate your class only using this constructor as the compiler doesn't add a default no-arg constructor to it as it already has a constructor(with one argument). Therefore, `A a = new A(1)` would work whereas `A a = new A()` would not.

If you want to be able to create a instance like this, `A a = new A()`, then you need to explicitly add a no-arg constructor to your class, like this

```
class A {
    public A(int b) { // single argument constructor
    }
    public A() { // no argument constructor
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad, that you have reread the question, and got it right. So, your answer is accepted!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using below code instead of example 2 then it will produce compilation error. IIOException is work like this. so you get the compilation error in example 1.

```
public class ConstructorChain
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            ClassB b = new ClassB();
        }
    }
class ClassA
{
    public ClassA()
    {
        System.out.println("Class A");
    } 
}

/** put in ClassB.java */
 class ClassB
    extends ClassA
{
     ClassB(String str)
     {

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a class has no constructors (as in ClassB), then according to Java Language Specification [8.8.9 "Default constructor"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9):
"**If a class contains no constructor declarations**, **then a default constructor with no formal parameters** and no throws clause **is implicitly declared**."

So, if the class has at least one constructor, then it should have it's own declaration of no-arg constructor to have it actually.

So if the ClassB has at least one constructor

```
/** put in ClassB.java */
public class ClassB
    extends ClassA
{
    public ClassB(String s)
    {
    }
}
```

then it will not have a no-arg constructor unless it is defined explicitly:

```
/** put in ClassB.java */
public class ClassB
    extends ClassA
{
    public ClassB()
    {
    }

    public ClassB(String s)
    {
    }
}
```